# API returns 500 while running mule with jetty

Tags: mule, jetty, embedded-jetty, mule-esb

First of all it picks text/plain in content-type header and it shows headers as empty.

I am calling GET /myapp/v2/status API and app is deployed on mule ESB which is using jetty. I just can not understand these logs.

```
    2021-02-24;22:42:02.025 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transport.servlet.ServletResponseWriter [ensureContentTypeHeaderIsSet:190]
[:::::]-Using Content-Type from message header = text/plain
2021-02-24;22:42:02.025 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$CommitCallback@1feedc9e generate: NEED_HEADER (null,[p=0,l=0,c=0,r=0],false)@START
2021-02-24;22:42:02.025 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$CommitCallback@1feedc9e generate: FLUSH ([p=0,l=131,c=8192,r=131],[p=0,l=0,c=0,r=0],false)@COMMITTED
2021-02-24;22:42:02.025 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-write: WriteFlusher@18e402ed{IDLE} [HeapByteBuffer@5534dd6[p=0,l=131,c=8192,r=131]={<<<HTTP/1.1 500 Serv...t-Length: 0||||>>>|http.status: 200...}]
2021-02-24;22:42:02.026 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
```

Mule Flow:

```
<flow name="myAppHealthChecks" doc:name="myApp Health Check Services">
<composite-source>
    <inbound-endpoint ref="StatusSvcExternalEndpoint">
        <not-filter>
            <wildcard-filter pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
        </not-filter>
    </inbound-endpoint>
    <inbound-endpoint ref="StatusSvcInternalEndpoint">
        <not-filter>
            <wildcard-filter pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
        </not-filter>
    </inbound-endpoint>
</composite-source>
<jersey:resources doc:name="Status Service Component">
    <component>
        <spring-object bean="statusService"/>
    </component>
    <jersey:context-resolver class="com.it.is.abs.core.http.myAppJAXBContextProvider"/>
</jersey:resources>
```

Full Logs

```
2021-02-24;22:42:01.994 [qtp1853662226-95] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Input@47d5420f{HttpChannelOverHttp@43eace2d{r=1,a=IDLE,uri=-},HttpConnection@6a6d1194{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of 0}} shutdown
2021-02-24;22:42:01.994 [qtp1853662226-95] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-HttpChannelOverHttp@43eace2d{r=1,a=IDLE,uri=-} handle enter
2021-02-24;22:42:01.994 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-REQUEST /myapp/v2/status on HttpChannelOverHttp@43eace2d{r=1,a=DISPATCHED,uri=/myapp/v2/status}
2021-02-24;22:42:01.994 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-scope null||/myapp/v2/status @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5092d2c6{/,null,AVAILABLE,@0.0.0.0:8888}
2021-02-24;22:42:01.995 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-scope null||/myapp/v2/status @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5092d2c6{/,null,AVAILABLE,@0.0.0.0:8888}
2021-02-24;22:42:01.995 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-scope null||/myapp/v2/status @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1b0642b8{/,null,AVAILABLE,@0.0.0.0:8889}
2021-02-24;22:42:01.995 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-context=||/myapp/v2/status @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1b0642b8{/,null,AVAILABLE,@0.0.0.0:8889}
2021-02-24;22:42:01.995 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-servlet ||/myapp/v2/status -> org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyReceiverServlet-6ac4efa8@be63ce8==org.mule.transport.servlet.jetty.JettyReceiverServlet,-1,true
2021-02-24;22:42:01.995 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-chain=null
2021-02-24;22:42:01.995 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse [registerSourceType:175]
[:::::]-java.lang.Object has been added as source type for this transformer, there will be no source type checking performed
2021-02-24;22:42:01.995 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage [setPropertyInternal:514]
[:::::]-setProperty(key, value) called with null value; removing key: MULE_CHARACTER_ENCODING
2021-02-24;22:42:01.996 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper [process:67]
[:::::]-Invoking InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper 'wrapper for InboundEndpoint 'http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2' composite request/response chain'
[
  InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper 'wrapper for InboundEndpoint 'http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2' request chain'
  [
    org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundEndpointMimeTypeCheckingMessageProcessor,
    org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundEndpointPropertyMessageProcessor,
    org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundNotificationMessageProcessor,
    org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundLoggingMessageProcessor,
    org.mule.routing.filters.logic.NotFilter (wrapped by MessageFilter),
    org.mule.source.StartableCompositeMessageSource$InternalMessageProcessor
  ],
  InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper 'wrapper for InboundEndpoint 'http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2' response chain'
  [
    org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundExceptionDetailsMessageProcessor,
    org.mule.routing.requestreply.ReplyToPropertyRequestReplyReplier
  ]
] with event MuleEvent: 0-9104fcc1-7734-11eb-a6b5-005056a03556, stop processing=false, http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:01.996 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain [process:67]
[:::::]-Invoking SimpleMessageProcessorChain
[
  InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper 'wrapper for InboundEndpoint 'http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2' request chain'
  [
    org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundEndpointMimeTypeCheckingMessageProcessor,
    org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundEndpointPropertyMessageProcessor,
    org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundNotificationMessageProcessor,
    org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundLoggingMessageProcessor,
    org.mule.routing.filters.logic.NotFilter (wrapped by MessageFilter),
    org.mule.source.StartableCompositeMessageSource$InternalMessageProcessor
  ],
  InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper 'wrapper for InboundEndpoint 'http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2' response chain'
  [
    org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundExceptionDetailsMessageProcessor,
    org.mule.routing.requestreply.ReplyToPropertyRequestReplyReplier
  ]
] with event MuleEvent: 0-9104fcc1-7734-11eb-a6b5-005056a03556, stop processing=false, http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:01.996 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper [process:67]
[:::::]-Invoking InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper 'wrapper for InboundEndpoint 'http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2' request chain'
[
  org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundEndpointMimeTypeCheckingMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundEndpointPropertyMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundNotificationMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundLoggingMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.routing.filters.logic.NotFilter (wrapped by MessageFilter),
  org.mule.source.StartableCompositeMessageSource$InternalMessageProcessor
] with event MuleEvent: 0-9104fcc1-7734-11eb-a6b5-005056a03556, stop processing=false, http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:01.997 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain [process:67]
[:::::]-Invoking SimpleMessageProcessorChain
[
  org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundEndpointMimeTypeCheckingMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundEndpointPropertyMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundNotificationMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundLoggingMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.routing.filters.logic.NotFilter (wrapped by MessageFilter)
] with event MuleEvent: 0-9104fcc1-7734-11eb-a6b5-005056a03556, stop processing=false, http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:01.997 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundLoggingMessageProcessor [process:35]
[:::::]-Message Received on: http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:01.997 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper [process:67]
[:::::]-Invoking InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper 'wrapper for 'myappHealthChecks' processor chain'
[
  org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1,
  org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$ProcessIfPipelineStartedMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.interceptor.ProcessingTimeInterceptor,
  org.mule.construct.processor.FlowConstructStatisticsMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.processor.LaxSedaStageInterceptingMessageProcessor,
  JerseyResourcesComponent{myappHealthChecks.component.745295748},
  org.mule.routing.requestreply.AsyncReplyToPropertyRequestReplyReplier,
  org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$2@7dc628cf
] with event MuleEvent: 0-9104fcc1-7734-11eb-a6b5-005056a03556, stop processing=false, http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:01.997 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain [process:67]
[:::::]-Invoking DefaultMessageProcessorChain '(inner iterating chain) of 'myappHealthChecks' processor chain'
[
  org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1
] with event MuleEvent: 0-9104fcc1-7734-11eb-a6b5-005056a03556, stop processing=false, http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:01.997 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain [process:67]
[:::::]-Invoking DefaultMessageProcessorChain '(inner iterating chain) of 'myappHealthChecks' processor chain'
[
  org.mule.construct.processor.FlowConstructStatisticsMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor
] with event MuleEvent: 0-9104fcc1-7734-11eb-a6b5-005056a03556, stop processing=false, http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:01.998 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain [process:67]

[:::::]-Invoking DefaultMessageProcessorChain '(inner iterating chain) of 'myappHealthChecks' processor chain'

[
  JerseyResourcesComponent{myappHealthChecks.component.745295748},
  org.mule.routing.requestreply.AsyncReplyToPropertyRequestReplyReplier
] with event MuleEvent: 0-9104fcc1-7734-11eb-a6b5-005056a03556, stop processing=false, http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:01.998 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper [process:67]
[:::::]-Invoking InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper 'wrapper for Component interceptor processor chain for :myappHealthChecks.component.745295748'
[
  org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1$1@ae65900
] with event MuleEvent: 0-9104fcc1-7734-11eb-a6b5-005056a03556, stop processing=false, http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:01.998 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain [process:67]
[:::::]-Invoking DefaultMessageProcessorChain '(inner iterating chain) of Component interceptor processor chain for :myappHealthChecks.component.745295748'
[
  org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1$1@ae65900
] with event MuleEvent: 0-9104fcc1-7734-11eb-a6b5-005056a03556, stop processing=false, http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:01.999 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent [buildRequest:273]
[:::::]-Base URI: http://myapp-sl2.qal2.dca.diginsite.net:8889/myapp/v2/
2021-02-24;22:42:01.999 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent [buildRequest:274]
[:::::]-Complete URI: http://myapp-sl2.qal2.dca.diginsite.net:8889/myapp/v2/status
2021-02-24;22:42:02.000 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToInputStream [transform:411]
[:::::]-Applying transformer _ObjectToInputStream (org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToInputStream)
2021-02-24;22:42:02.000 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToInputStream [transform:412]
[:::::]-Object before transform: /myapp/v2/status
2021-02-24;22:42:02.000 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToInputStream [transform:424]
[:::::]-Object after transform: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@5a8c3df9
2021-02-24;22:42:02.000 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer [checkTransformerReturnClass:197]
[:::::]-The transformed value is of expected type. Type is: ByteArrayInputStream
2021-02-24;22:42:02.022 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage [applyAllTransformers:1543]
[:::::]-Using TransformerTemplate{this=879b82b, name='null', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, sourceTypes=[]} to transform payload.
2021-02-24;22:42:02.022 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transformer.TransformerTemplate [transform:112]
[:::::]-Applying transformer TransformerTemplate (org.mule.transformer.TransformerTemplate)
2021-02-24;22:42:02.023 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transformer.TransformerTemplate [transform:155]
[:::::]-Object after transform: org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent$2@71782a9a
2021-02-24;22:42:02.023 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transformer.TransformerTemplate [checkReturnClass:187]
[:::::]-The transformed object is of expected type. Type is: JerseyResourcesComponent$2
2021-02-24;22:42:02.024 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper [process:67]
[:::::]-Invoking InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper 'wrapper for InboundEndpoint 'http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2' response chain'
[
  org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundExceptionDetailsMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.routing.requestreply.ReplyToPropertyRequestReplyReplier
] with event MuleEvent: 0-9104fcc1-7734-11eb-a6b5-005056a03556, stop processing=false, http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:02.024 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain [process:67]
[:::::]-Invoking SimpleMessageProcessorChain
[
  org.mule.endpoint.inbound.InboundExceptionDetailsMessageProcessor,
  org.mule.routing.requestreply.ReplyToPropertyRequestReplyReplier
] with event MuleEvent: 0-9104fcc1-7734-11eb-a6b5-005056a03556, stop processing=false, http://0.0.0.0:8889/myapp/v2
2021-02-24;22:42:02.024 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse [transform:112]
[:::::]-Applying transformer MuleMessageToHttpResponse (org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse)
2021-02-24;22:42:02.025 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse [transform:155]
[:::::]-Object after transform: org.mule.transport.http.HttpResponse@5a938f07
2021-02-24;22:42:02.025 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse [checkReturnClass:187]
[:::::]-The transformed object is of expected type. Type is: HttpResponse
2021-02-24;22:42:02.025 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.mule.transport.servlet.ServletResponseWriter [ensureContentTypeHeaderIsSet:190]
[:::::]-Using Content-Type from message header = text/plain
2021-02-24;22:42:02.025 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$CommitCallback@1feedc9e generate: NEED_HEADER (null,[p=0,l=0,c=0,r=0],false)@START
2021-02-24;22:42:02.025 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$CommitCallback@1feedc9e generate: FLUSH ([p=0,l=131,c=8192,r=131],[p=0,l=0,c=0,r=0],false)@COMMITTED
2021-02-24;22:42:02.025 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-write: WriteFlusher@18e402ed{IDLE} [HeapByteBuffer@5534dd6[p=0,l=131,c=8192,r=131]={<<<HTTP/1.1 500 Serv...t-Length: 0||||>>>|http.status: 200...}]
2021-02-24;22:42:02.026 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-update WriteFlusher@18e402ed{WRITING}:IDLE-->WRITING
2021-02-24;22:42:02.026 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-flushed 131 SelectChannelEndPoint@62b1924c{/10.102.144.96:4680<r-l>/10.102.146.111:8889,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@1dcf1e2a{false,null},wf=WriteFlusher@18e402ed{WRITING},it=30000}{HttpConnection@6a6d1194{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=COMMITTED},p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of 0}}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
2021-02-24;22:42:02.026 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-flushed true
2021-02-24;22:42:02.026 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-update WriteFlusher@18e402ed{IDLE}:WRITING-->IDLE
2021-02-24;22:42:02.026 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$CommitCallback@1feedc9e generate: DONE ([p=131,l=131,c=8192,r=0],[p=0,l=0,c=0,r=0],false)@COMMITTED
2021-02-24;22:42:02.027 [qtp1853662226-95 - /myapp/v2/status] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty [debug:80]
[:::::]-RESPONSE /myapp/v2/status  500 handled=true
```

Same code runs fine in one environment and not working in one environment.

Comment: Those log entries show normal operation of Jetty, and returning an error 500 with no body content to the client.  The limited logs you are showing do not indicate if that 500 is from Jetty itself, or your webapp.

Comment: The fact that there is no body content on that 500 means it likely wasn't generated by Jetty (as Jetty will include details in its handling of 500 in the response body)

Comment: but I can see headers in my Mule message {http.headers={tid=c7122f-46-42-a31c-7b806c4809da, User-Agent=SuperMon, Connection=keep-alive, id=10046, X-Forwarded-For=61.111.231.5, 10.126.124.26, payment_app_token=, Host=qal.ss.com:8888, Content-Type=application/xml}}

Comment: That looks like your request headers (the existence of the `User-Agent` and `Host` headers tells me that) and your pasted logs are from when the response is committed (well after the request has been parsed and handled)

Comment: Ok, so maybe as part of mule flow it is creating intermediate response and then passing it on to another flow.

Strange thing is I have put many debug logs starting from controller to service but none got printed. I am assuming that request is not even reaching controller code.

Comment: What version of Mule exactly? Please also share details of the Jetty configuration and flow.

Comment: Mule version 3.9.0

Comment: Added flow and full log

Comment: What is the message in the 500 response? Seems truncated in the log `<<<HTTP/1.1 500 Serv...`.
What is the configuration of the endpoints? What happens in the flow after the composite-endpoint? Is there a logger somewhere? Are you using DataWeave?

Comment: Well that's what I'm trying to figure out. No, all flows are these in logs.

Comment: So I found the issue the code reaches the server and then an exception is raised which is causing this issue. Strange thing is all INFO server logs are seen when I moved all mule, spring, server logs to TRACE.